# Regex on security path in Symfony 2

Tags: regex, symfony

I'm trying to have a regex working for strings that exactly matches 2 or 3 long lowcase letters, in order to match /es/user ,  en/user ,  cat/user

```
 - { path: ^/[a-z]+/user, role: [ROLE_USER]}
```

is working but is not limiting to 2-3 letters length.

```
- { path: ^/[a-z]\{2,3}/user, role: [ROLE_USER]}
```

causes this error:

```
InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "3\}/user," under "security.access_control.0"
```

Comment: if it causes error then try to escape the curly braces.

Comment: Forward slashes must be escaped

Comment: - { path: ^/[a-z]{2,3}/user, role: [ROLE_USER]}  - { path: ^/[a-z]{2,3}\/user, role: [ROLE_USER]} none of them not working

Comment: Still not working, btw I'm using Symfony 2.46

Comment: Could you try out this regex: `^(\/?)*[a-z]{1,3}+\/\w+$`?

Comment: - { path: ^/(\/?)*[a-z]{1,3}+\/\w+/user, role: [ROLE_USER]}


InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "3}+\/\w+/user," under "security.access_control.0"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single-quotes ( ' ), or double-quotes ( " ).

```
- { path: '^/[a-z]\{2,3}/user', role: [ROLE_USER]}
```